# Adding different polygons to raster stack plot using levelplot in R

Tags: r, graphics, spatial, polygons, levelplot

Is there a way to add a different polygon to a raster stack plot built using levelplot?  For example, I plotted a raster stack comprised of 6 rasters.  I would like to add a different polygon to each panel.  However, when I add a layer, that layer is repeated across all six panels & my attempts to add addition polygons are result in those also being added to each panel.

```
#plot raster stack
levelplot(rStack, margin=F, xlab="", ylab="", 
par.settings=list(strip.background=list(col="lightgray")), 
names.attr=c("18000BP", "15000BP", "12000BP", "6000BP", "2050", "2090"),
      scales = list(draw=F))
```

[levelplot of raster stack without polygons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qS9fm.png)

```
#plot raster stack & add polygons
levelplot(rStack, margin=F, xlab="", ylab="", 
par.settings=list(strip.background=list(col="lightgray")), 
names.attr=c("18000BP", "15000BP", "12000BP", "6000BP", "2050", "2090"),
      scales = list(draw=F)) + 
layer(sp.polygons(ice1)) + layer(sp.polygons(ice2))
```

[levelplot with two polygons added, which are repeated across all panels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLQSr.png)

Comment: Please supply a reproducible example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 3):

Here's a silly example using the `packets` argument in `latticeExtra::layer`. If you wanted to, you could just add layer after layer like this.

```
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)
library(sp)

Sr1 = Polygon(cbind(c(2, 4, 4, 1, 2), c(2, 3, 5, 4, 2)))
Sr2 = Polygon(cbind(c(5, 4, 2, 5), c(2, 3, 2, 2)))
Sr3 = Polygon(cbind(c(4, 4, 5, 10, 4), c(5, 3, 2, 5, 5)))
Sr4 = Polygon(cbind(c(5, 6, 6, 5, 5), c(4, 4, 3, 3, 4)), hole = TRUE)

Srs1 = Polygons(list(Sr1), "s1")
Srs2 = Polygons(list(Sr2), "s2")
Srs3 = Polygons(list(Sr3, Sr4), "s3/4")
SpP = SpatialPolygons(list(Srs1, Srs2, Srs3), 1:3)

levelplot(rnorm(10, 10) ~ 1:10 + runif(10, 1, 10) | rep(c("A", "B"),each = 5)) +
  layer(sp.polygons(SpP), packets = 1)
```

[image: Imgur]

Comment: It worked for me. So, just add `packets = n`, with n the number of the plot you want that layer to be added to, and use `layer` as many times as you need. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ggplot2` with `rasterVis`, this will give you more flexibility. The `facet_wrap` associated with the correct parameter will allow to separate polygons between raster layers views. To do so, you will have to modify the `id` column of your fortified spatial polygon to match raster `variable` column.
Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)
library(ggplot2)
library(sp)

# Raster object
fn <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
s <- stack(fn, fn)
names(s) <- c("A", "B")

# Two polygons
pol.A <- data.frame(x = c(179000, 179000, 180000, 180000),
                    y = c(330000, 331000, 331000, 330000))
pol.B <- data.frame(x = c(180000, 180000, 181000, 181000),
                    y = c(331000, 332000, 332000, 331000))
# Transform as Spatial Polygons to fit your example
pol.sp <- SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(pol.A)), "A"),
                                 Polygons(list(Polygon(pol.B)), "B")))
# Use Fortify to be able to use SpatialPolygons with ggplot2
# rename id as "variable" to correspond to rasterstack gplot output
pol.sp.fort <- fortify(pol.sp) %>%
  rename(variable = id)

# Plot. Note that gplot is not ggplot and issued from library rasterVis
gplot(s) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) +
  geom_polygon(data = pol.sp.fort, aes(long, lat), col = "red") + 
  facet_wrap(~ variable)
```